# Not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I'm trying to compile C++ code(within Sublime) and I'm getting error

```
'"arm-none-eabi-g++"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

But if I compile same code within ArduinoIDE I get no errors. So I searched and found I should add path to system environment. So, I fould "arm-none-eabi-g++.exe" and added path to the file, reboot PC but still get that error.

[image]
[image: 2nd path]

Comment: How did setup sublime to use `Ardino_PATH`? Just because 1 IDE combines this value into the system PATH does not mean it will be automatic on any other IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't make a variable named after the tool name and put the EXE's full path in it. You need to edit the variable named `Path` there in the list, and add the path to the *folder* that the EXE is in, followed by `;`, in front of what is already there.

Comment: It Works I guess. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not so uncommon to create new environmental variable and then add them to the PATH environmental variable. By default, each path is limited to 260 characters, so this is a way to reduce its length. Windows 10 [allows longer paths](https://lifehacker.com/windows-10-allows-file-names-longer-than-260-characters-1785201032), but its not a system default.